# Attribute onclick triggers click event automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I set `onclick` attribute using [jquery](https://jquery.com/), the method is getting called. This is happening only if I use tab key to trigger the link. When I click on the link, no issue occurs. Is this known bug? Please find the code snippet below. However I am not able to reproduce the issue in it and my code is exactly the same.

FYI, I am using jquery 3.1.1.

```js
function setDeleteLogo() {
  $('#deleteLogoBtn').attr('onclick', $('#confirmLink').attr('data-onclick'));
}

function deleteLogo() {
  alert();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="confirmLink" onclick="setDeleteLogo()" href="javascript:;" data-onclick="deleteLogo()">Confirm</a>

<button id="deleteLogoBtn">Yes, Delete</button>
```

Comment: Seems XY problem to me, What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I edited the post. When I click on "Confirm" link, I am trying to get `data-onclick` from the link and set it to "Yes, Delete" button's onclick. When I do that, `deleteLogo()` called automatically.

Comment: It will not call automatically. `$('#deleteLogoBtn').attr('onclick', $('#confirmLink').attr('data-onclick'));` will add the `onclick` event with value as `deleteLogo()` to the button. What is the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why can't you bind the click event to the element directly? Do you only want to allow deletion of the logo on second click? What you're trying to do is unclear.

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh, if i guess correct, i think you're trying to replace the attribute of data-onclick

Comment: @Terry I am trying to open a confirm popup on first click and then delete method will call

Answer (score 0):

.attr is used to enable/disable attributes of a particular element.
for e.g.
    ('#button').attr('disabled','disabled') where first parameter is atrribute name and second parameter is the value we want to set.
Please try using 
    yourElement.click(function() {
     ....
    })

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your example a bit:

- The button receives a click handler that determines what is called.
- The confirmation link receives a click handler on first visit.
- This click handler of the link triggers a click event on the button.
- The link holds a data attribute (`data-confirmed`) whose presence indicates that is has been visited.

You may want additional logic to have a dynamic call target instead of hard-coded  `deleteLogo` and reset the status of the confirmation link.

```js
function setDeleteLogo() {
    if (!$('#confirmLink').attr('data-confirmed')) {
        $('#confirmLink').on('click', () => { $("#deleteLogoBtn").trigger("click"); 1; });
        $('#confirmLink').attr('data-confirmed', '1');
    }
}

function deleteLogo() {
  alert();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="confirmLink" onclick="setDeleteLogo()" href="javascript:;">Confirm</a>

<button id="deleteLogoBtn" onclick="deleteLogo()" data-onclick="deleteLogo()">Yes, Delete</button>
```